# Check the string is ending with "|" using python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to check whether the string ends with `|` or not.

```
Student,"Details"
Joe|"December 2017|maths"
Bob|"April 2018|History|Biology|Physics|"
sam|"December 2018|physics"
```

I have tried with the below code and it's not working as expected.

```py
def Pipe_in_variant(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='|')
    mask = (df['Details'])
    result = mask.endswith(""|"")
    print("...................")
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example input is unclear, however assuming you want to check is items in a column end with something, use [`str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html).

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Details': ['ab|c', 'acb|']})

df['Details'].str.endswith('|')
```

output:

```
0    False
1     True
Name: Details, dtype: bool
```

###### printing the matching rows:

```
df[df['Details'].str.endswith('|')]
```

output:

```
  Details
1    acb|
```

Comment: Is it possible to print the matching line here it is :Bob|"April 2018|History|Biology|Physics|"

Comment: @Sreerag sure, see updated answer

Comment: I have changed as per the suggestion but again its not working for me. 
    df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='|')
    dd = df.DataFrame({'Details': ['ab|c', 'acb|']})
    mask=dd[dd['Details'].endswith('|')]
    print(dd[mask])

Comment: @Daniel Walker: Worked Perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Note - I think first row of input should be `Student|"Details"` instead of `Student,"Details"`.

Here is what you can do

```
import pandas as pd
dframe = pd.read_csv('input.txt', sep='|')
dframe['ends_with_vbar'] = dframe['Details'].str.endswith('|')
dframe
```

Output:

```
  Student                              Details  ends_with_vbar
0     Joe                  December 2017|maths           False
1     Bob  April 2018|History|Biology|Physics|            True
2     sam                December 2018|physics           False
```

Then you can print the marked row as follows

```
for _, row in dframe[dframe['ends_with_vbar']].iterrows():
    print(f'{row["Student"]} - {row["Details"]}')
```

Output:

```
Bob - April 2018|History|Biology|Physics|
```

Comment: Using iterrows on such a task is not a good solution. It would be better to simply select all entries that meet the condition and output them at once.

Comment: iterrows is done after the selection using `dframe[dframe['ends_with_vbar']]`

Comment: is there any way i can check the empty string or null value for the above input.

Comment: You can filter out null rows before doing the `endswith` using `dframe = dframe[dframe['Detaisl'].isnull() == False]`